# Can't put Nvidia GPU in TCC mode

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I am trying to connect to a remote computer with Nvidia Tesla M2070q GPU. I am trying to put the device in TCC mode with this:

```
nvidia-smi -g 0 -dm 0
```

but gives me the following error:

> Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error

The remote computer has two graphic cards, Nvidia Tesla M2070q and some ATI.

Other information: I can't open Nvidia control panel via remote desktop, it gives me the following error message:

> You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Remote desktop uses a virtual graphics driver so the control panel is not accessible.  You would need to log in directly.  It is not done by the control panel anyway.

This is what I have done.  Run a CMD window as Administrator -- right click to launch run as Administrator.  CD to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI. Run nvidia-smi.exe with no arguments to see what the command arguments are.  Use -q to query the status.  Use -dm to toggle TCC mode. Use separate argument -i to target a specific device.   The setting is tentative.  Reboot to make it permanent.

Once the TCC settings are in place, you should be able to launch programs from remote desktop that will access the TCC mode driver.

Comment: What was your second attached display ? on that remote server it has an ATI attached to display. will this be an issue ? because doing the step above from local stand Still with the same error

Comment: `You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU` I am not sure if this is still the case, but in early cuda days: Attach either a display (no need to actually look at it) or shove a resistor into the cards VGA port to make it think it has an connected display.